# How to unit test this code

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I googled on how to unit test but examples are so simple. the examples always show functions that return something or do ajax that returns something - but never have i seen examples that do callbacks, nested callbacks and functions that are "one-way", that they just store something and never return anything.

say i have a code like this, how should i go about testing it?

```
(function(){
    var cache = {};

    function dependencyLoader(dependencies,callback2){
        //loads a script to the page, and notes it in the cache
        if(allLoaded){
            callback2()
        }
    }

    function moduleLoader(dependencies, callback1){
        dependencyLoader(dependencies,function(){
            //do some setup
            callback1()
        });
    }

    window.framework = {
        moduleLoader : moduleLoader
    }

}());


framework.moduleLoader(['foo','bar','baz'],function(){
    //call when all is loaded
})
```

Comment: I believe you have a typo, it should say `moduleloader : moduleLoader` or else it would be undefined. this should've been picked up by a unit test. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This illustrates a problem with keeping things private in an anonymous function in javascript. It's a bit difficult to validate that things are working internally.

If this was done test first then the cache, dependencyLoader and moduleLoader should be publicly available on the framework object. Or else it would be difficult to validate that the cache was handled properly.

To get things going I'd recommend you take a gander on [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development), that conveniently gives you an approach to help you start by letting you spell out the behaviour with a `given-when-then` convention. I like to use [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/), which is a javascript BDD framework (that integrates with `jstestdriver`), for this kind of thing and the unit tests I'd make for the sample you have above would be:

```
describe('given the moduleloader is clear', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        // clear cache
        // remove script tag
    });

    describe('when one dependency is loaded', function() {

        beforeEach(function() {
            // load a dependency
        });

        it('then should be in cache', function() {
            // check the cache
        });

        it('then should be in a script tag', function() {
            // check the script tag
        });

        describe('when the same dependency is loaded', function() {

            beforeEach(function () {
                // attempt to load the same dependency again
            });

            it('then should only occur once in cache', function() {
                // validate it only occurs once in the cache
            });

            it('then should only occur once in script tag', function() {
                // validate it only occurs once in the script tag
            });

        });
    });

    // I let the exercise of writing tests for loading multiple modules to the OP

});
```

Hope these tests are self explanatory. I tend to rewrite the tests so that they nest nicely, and usually the actual calls are done in the `beforeEach` functions while the validation are done in the `it` functions.

Comment: Alternatively use [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) instead of jasmine, though I personally don't have experience with it but it has similar constructs.